# Upgrading Azure VM Windows Edition

Tags: windows, azure, virtual-machine, server

I have a Windows Server 2008 Azure VM. Is there a way I can upgrade my VM to Windows Server 2012 without reinstalling everything?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just as with a local VM you are responsible for the upgrade, you will need to download the new Server 2012 software and run the setup/upgrade of Windows.

Automatical upgrades are only possible with the PaaS Cloud Services (but these are stateless)